# argparse - Modify the 'required' state of a subcommand's parent arguments

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to build a CLI in Python and I have an argument (--arg) that I want to reuse across multiple subcommands (req and opt).

But one subcommand (req) will have to require --arg and the other (opt) doesn't. How do I resolve this without having to make two versions of the same argument?

```py
import argparse
arg_1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
arg_1.add_argument('-a', '--arg', required=True,
                    help='reusable argument')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser.add_subparsers()

cmd_require = subp.add_parser('req', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand requires --arg')  
cmd_optional = subp.add_parser('opt', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand doesn\'t require --arg')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any 'native' argparse feature that does that. However, I thought of 2 different approaches to solve your problem.

**Validate args in a separate function** - 
Sometimes CLI application get complicated and by adding a validator function you can 'complete' the missing argparse features you wish for.

```
import argparse
arg_1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
arg_1.add_argument('-a', '--arg', required=False,
                    help='reusable argument')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='sub_parser')

cmd_require = subp.add_parser('req', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand requires --arg')  
cmd_optional = subp.add_parser('opt', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand doesn\'t require --arg') 

def validate_args(args):
    print(args)
    if args.sub_parser == 'req' and not args.arg:
        print("Invalid usage! using 'req' requires 'arg'")
        exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    validate_args(args)
```

*Note:*

1. I used `dest` for the subparser in order to later identify the chosen 
   subparser.
2. Using argparse, if an optional argument is not passed it will be 'None'

**"prepared argument"** -
Although argparse doesn't support an `argument` object - you could 'prepare' an argument by unpacking a dict and a tuple (*args, **kwargs)

```
import argparse
arg_name = ('-a', '--arg')
arg_dict = {'help': 'reusable argument'}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser.add_subparsers()

cmd_require = subp.add_parser('req',
                                help='this subcommand requires --arg')  
cmd_optional = subp.add_parser('opt',
                                help='this subcommand doesn\'t require --arg') 

cmd_optional.add_argument(*arg_name, **arg_dict, required=False)
cmd_require.add_argument(*arg_name, **arg_dict, required=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    validate_args(args)
```

I like the first approach better.

Hope you find that useful

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
arg_1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
foobar = arg_1.add_argument('-a', '--arg', required=True,
                    help='reusable argument')
```

`arg_1` is a `parser` object.  When you use the `add_argument` command, it creates an `Action` object and adds it to the `args_1._actions` list.  I just saved a reference to that in the `foobar` variable.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser.add_subparsers()
```

The `parents` mechanism adds the `args_1._actions` list to the `cmd_require._actions` list.  So `foobar` will appear in both subparsers.  It's copy by reference, which is common in python.

```
cmd_require = subp.add_parser('req', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand requires --arg')  
cmd_optional = subp.add_parser('opt', parents=[arg_1],
                                help='this subcommand doesn\'t require --arg')
```

`foobar.required=False` will turn off at attribute, but will do so for both parsers.   I've seen this issue come up when people wanted to assign different `default` attributes.

The `parents` mechanism just a shortcut, that occasionally is useful, but not always.  It doesn't do anything special; just saves a bit of typing.  There are plenty other ways of defining an Action with the same flags in both subparsers.

- typing it twice (horror of horrors!)
- copy-n-paste
- writing a utility function to add arguments to subparsers  (see Larry Wall's [Three Virtues](http://threevirtues.com/))